# How To Get Backlinks From Search Directories or Coupon Websites?

Tags: seo, backlinks

How do I get SEO backlinks from free search directory and coupon websites?

When I am doing competitor analysis for my website, my competitors are getting backlinks from these types of websites. As there are no option to sign up or contact then how my competitor getting backlinks from these types of websites?

If these types of websites have their own crawlers then why these are not crawling my website as per my competitors?

Answer (score 2):

Every site is different. Many of them aggregate data so you need to insert them at the source. If there is a free listing or sign up page you can use site: operator to try and find them.

Generally speaking these directory links do not help that much but opinions differ. There may be a handful of them that are truly useful for rankings or driving traffic or getting leads.

Not every link is worth getting. Sometimes the (link) juice isn’t worth the squeeze.